# Fg limit frequency calculation. Active band-pass filter

Tags: active-filter

I need help with calculating the cutoff frequency Fg. There are several formulas, but I don't know which one to use because every time I get out a different value in (Hz).

Below is the schematic of this filter (active band pass filter) + its characteristics.(The initial scheme was wrong what neil uk noticed . thanks)

I care about the correct solution :)
[image]

characteristics (calculated using excel):
[image]
At first I want to correct that I drew the schematics and characktistics myself and I have a measurement table for them . I am not 100% sure about what I drew , but it seems to me that there is a fmeasure otherwise fg but it is calculated with the value of delta f0 or delta f10 from the characterization . I marked fmeasure for -3dB delta f0 and -20 dB delta f10 .

But I still need fcalc (calculated from the formula to later calculate the percentage of measurement error)
And from what I tried I got the formula in school .
fcalc=1/(2π√LC) but it seems that the formula is not correct or I don't know how to calculate it .
Using chat gpt I found out that there is a formula
Fg= fl+fh/2 Where fg is the cutoff frequency,fL is the lower cutoff frequency, and fH is the upper cutoff frequency . I don't know if the formula is correct and I did everything right but please correct me if necessary :)

Comment: write down your reasoning in the question for one or more of your attempts, so we can see what you know to have a better guess at where you're going wrong, and inline that image into your question so we don't have to chase links. At a quick glance, it may depend on the output impedance of the generator, which is not shown.

Comment: Your schematic is wrong. The axes on your plot are not listed. "fg" appears to be defined twice on that plot.

Comment: OseRu - Hi, That schematic looks like it has come from a publication. Please confirm its source. || Note that when a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore unless that schematic is your own work, please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source reference & remember to include references in future. Thanks

Comment: Andy aka -  I am not 100% sure about what I drew , but it seems to me that there is a fmeasure otherwise fg but it is calculated with the value of delta f0 or delta f10 from the characterization

Comment: Neil_UK - In what sense is the cut-off frequency supposed to depend on the impedance of the generator ?

Comment: @OseRu The amplifier as shown is low impedance at the base due to the collector feedback, which will affect the damping of the tuned collector load, and thus its corner frequencies. I'm making as assumption that the oscilloscope is a high load impedance like 1 Mohm, but that might not be true. When simulating a circuit, it's best to not make assumptions about input and output impedances.